# How to use Normalize in Redux - Form Fields component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a question about Redux Form

https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/normalizing/ - this one

I combined two inputs with Fields component, and in each of this input i wanna use Normalize method from Redux-Form, how i can do that?

Example:

```
<Fields 
  names={[ 'first', 'last' ]} 
  component={this.renderFields}
/>

const renderFields = (fields) => (
 <div>
  <input {...fields.first.input}>
  <input {...fields.first.input}>
 </div>
)
```

Comment: Is it important to have two `<input />` wrapped in a `<Fields /> `  component rather than just using using two `<Field />`  components in a div?

Comment: Any luck with my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to manually run the normalize functions:

```js
const renderFields = (fields) => {
  const first = fields.first;
  const onChangeFirst = (event) => {
     const newValue = event.target.value;
     // normalize is passed down as a prop as well
     const normalizedValue = fields.normalize(newValue);
     // pass the normalized value to the Redux-Form onChange
     first.input.onChange(normalizedValue);
  };

  const last = fields.last;
  // do the equivalent thing for "last"
  // const onChangeLast  .... ...

  return (
     <div>
       <input {...first.input} onChange={ onChangeFirst }>
       <input {...last.input} onChange={ onChangeLast } >
     </div>
  );
}
```

Then you would use it like

```js
<Fields 
  names={ [ 'first', 'last' ] } 
  component={ this.renderFields }
  normalize={ myNormalizeFunction }
/>
```

You can see a working [**JSFiddle demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/4non6918/).

Comment: Yes it help me) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Fields 
  names={ [ 'first', 'last' ] } 
  component={ this.renderFields }
  format={ (name, value) => {
    if(name === 'first') {
       //return something for [first value] like normalize function
    }
    //return something for [last value] like normalize function
  }}
/>
```